# Toast call inside of a button tap giving an error that i can't figure out

Tags: java, android, toast, buttonclick

I am trying to make a Toast that will display the information stored in the `text` variable when the `submitbtn` is clicked.  The error that I am getting is not with in the running of the code but with the Eclipse telling me :

> The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Class, String, int)

The file that the Toast is in is the UserInput.java file. Here is the current code block:

```
Button submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String text = null; 
            text = dayArray[position].toString();
            //Log.i("spinner test: ", text);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UserInput.class, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I have even tried to set the Context to `UserInput.this` and `getApplicationContext()` and that gives me this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Toast

I will let you know that I am a Android novice and somewhat of a Java novice but I have searched high and low and can not find any solutions that will work.  This Toast is also not important to the app I am developing so it could and will be taken out completely but I want to know why this will not work for my learning process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(UserInput.class, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(UserInput.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You need to use your `Activity` `Context` so you use `ActivityName.this`.

But your original problem is that if you are doing it this way then you need to just call it all statically because you are calling `show()`.

You could take off the `show()` and create an instance of `Toast` if you wanted to do other things with it such as call `setView()` to use a custom `View` for your `Toast`. Then call `show()` on the `Toast` instance you created.

Comment: Okay so one thing I take from this and correct me if wrong when showing the Toast in the same statement you do not need to build the variable part `Toast toast =` at the first of the syntax.

Comment: Correct because you are using it in a `static` context. Much like using a `ProgressDialog`

Comment: [The Docs Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html) may or may not make it more apparent